# Installing sqlite3 as a node.js module

Tags: python, node.js, sqlite

So I've been working on this since yesterday, and can't seem to get anywhere. I've tried to follow documentation, and various tutorials but none of them seem to work.

If I make a new folder, with a new Javascript file with the default usage code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});

db.close();
```

And then try to install sqlite3 through npm by typing into the node.js CMD:

```
cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sqlite3test 
npm install sqlite3
```

I'm greeted with this error message:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sqlite3test>npm install sqlite3
\
> sqlite3@3.1.0 install C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build


C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node  clean )

C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64 --python=c:\Python27\python.exe )  else (node  configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64 --python=c:\Python27\python.exe )

C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64 )  else (node  build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64 )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  unpack_sqlite_dep
  'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targ
ets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\User\node_mo
dules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\User\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v46-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\User\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v46-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.10
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\User\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v46-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sqlite3"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sqlite3test\npm-debug.log
```

Looking further through the documentation on the [NPM website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) regarding sqlite3, it says that I must meet "[node-gyp's requirements](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)". I have gone through and done all of these. If I set up the python environment beforehand using:

```
npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe
```

I get the same error message. I have no idea what's going on. Could it be because Windows 10 currently doesn't support the node-gyp requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows, try

```
set PYTHON=python2.7
```

Comment: I think you might be onto something. Due to the first line in the error being:
"python not recognized as an internal..."

Also, the requirements state that I must "Make sure that you have a PYTHON environment variable, and it is set to drive:\path\to\python.exe not to a folder". If I do "set PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe", it still throws the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the solution.

It turned out that my Python environment variable was not correctly set. I looked it up on another thread and found this solution posted by Delicia Brummitt:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21433154/4071682